# DataGrid calculated columns

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

I am trying to transfer my excel app to WPF datagrid. I am going to enter data to Column A and in column B I would like to make calculation taking previus cell and current cell of A column and add Column B previus cell. 
calculation example : B2 = B1 + (A2-A1). What is best approach of doing so?

Comment: Hang on. Just caught this. By "previous cell" do you mean on the previous *row*?

Comment: Yes, Cell of previous row of the same column. Current row is 2, so in cell (B2) I would like to make a calculation = B1 + (A2-A1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I'd start by creating a class that represents the records and implement INotifyPropertyChanged on that class.

```
public class recordObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int a;
    public int A 
    { 
        get
        {
            return a;
        }
        set
        {
            a = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("A");
        }
    }

    private int b;
    public int B
    { 
        get
        {
            return b;
        }
        set
        {
            b = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("B");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your code behind on the window you're showing the datagrid, you'll want to subscribe to PropertyChanged on each object in the list. Then you'd have to manually compute the column values whenever those properties changed. Ick, I know, but it'd work.

The property changed event would look like:

```
void recordObject_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var objectList = DataGrid.ItemsSource as List<recordObject>;
    var myRecord = sender as recordObject;
    if (objectList != null && myRecord != null)
    {
        int idx = objectList.IndexOf(myRecord);
        // Perform your calculations here using idx to access records before and after the current record
        // making sure to check for list boundaries for top and bottom.
        // Also note that this will likely kick off cascading event calls so make sure you're only changing
        // the previous or following record object.
    }
}
```

If you hook this event onto all the records in your bound list, then it'll fire whenever *any* property is changed. In the class above, that'd apply to both A and B. You can filter which properties you're interested in monitoring through e.PropertyName (a simple string comparison) and guage the business logic accordingly. If you want to maintain encapsulation, or at least, put the business logic for the object on the object itself, this method could be a static one on the class recordObject. You'd have to provide for getting hold of the datagrid from that static method, though (likely through a static property on your window). So:

```
public static void recordObject_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
```

and connected so:

```
record.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(recordObject.recordObject_PropertyChanged);
```

Comment: Wow, this is realy detailed answer thanks for that. As far as I understood your answer is focused on automatic update of Column B, which is welcomed but not at present stage. What I am looking for right now is business logic behind the scene.

Comment: Could you be more specific, Jim? All you've got by way of business logic in your question is B2 = B1 + (A2-A1). I thought your question was more general so I'm not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: i'll mark it as answered, however I have to study things you suggested and make a lot of tries and erros:)

Comment: In reply to your comment I am really interested in notes you are making in your code (e.g ...// Perform your calculations here using idx...will likely kick off cascading event ..... etc). Ideally I would put that logic in recordObject, but it seems imposible.

Comment: Not impossible. Just create a static DataGrid property on your window and assign your datagrid to it in Window_Loaded. That way you can reference your object collection as MyWindow.MyDataGrid.ItemsSource.

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to create a static DataGrid property and reference it in my object, but when I add new line in my datagrid this event is not fired at all. This is natural because new object is not wired with record.PropertyChanged . So how would I wire it correctly even when new object are created via datagrid input and not programmaticaly?

Comment: That's not a property change, that's a new object. You can catch it on the observable collection events.

Answer (score 4):

The best thing is to implement that logic in a class, and bind the grid to the respective properties.  For instance:

```
class SomeData 
{
  int A { get; set; }
  int B { get; set; }
  int AminusB { get { return A - B; } }
}
```

Comment: This exact solution wouldn't work for what is trying to be accomplished.  Each instance of SomeData would have to have a reference to the previous SomeData in order to calculate B each time dependent on the values of A and B on the previous SomeData.

Comment: Good catch, Adam. I'd missed that in my answer as well.

Comment: Thanks, I have implemented your solution (Nick and Jacob) to make an calculation on the same row without any problem. However I still cant understand on how to get previous row Cell and add it to current row's Cell  B2 = B1 + (A2-A1)